# BizTalk WCF-Custom send port oracle System.NullReferenceException

Tags: oracle, biztalk, biztalk-2013

I have a setup where a file containing the "query" in XML structure

```
<ns0:Select xmlns:ns0="http://Microsoft.LobServices.OracleDB/2007/03/XAL_SUPERVISOR/View/VIEW_FLEETLIST">
    <ns0:COLUMN_NAMES>*</ns0:COLUMN_NAMES> 
    <ns0:FILTER>department not in ('95','96','97','99','601','995','999')</ns0:FILTER> 
</ns0:Select>
```

This is then supposed to be picked up by a orchestration that sends the message to an oracle database through a WCF-Custom adapter

But when I try I get this rather non descriptive error message:

```
A message sent to adapter "WCF-Custom" on send port "FleetList.Oracle.XALADK" with URI
"oracledb://XALADK" is suspended. 
Error details: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Server stack trace: 
   at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.SendAsyncResult.End(SendAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndCall(String action, Object[] outs, IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.IRequestChannel.EndRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Runtime.WcfClient`2.RequestCallback(IAsyncResult result) 
 MessageId:  {2EECDD75-2CDC-4406-B8D9-59B1C0012D95}
 InstanceID: {645666FB-3881-4899-9A10-63CFD54C27A3}
```

And now I'm at a complete loss...

Comment: It looks like a communication failure of some sort, possible with proxy settings, can you give us some details about the ports configuration & environment (e.g. proxies & firewalls)?  Although that NULL exception indicates that it may be at the config side.